# How to remove LAST INSTANCE of a character from a string

Tags: c#, asp.net, string, character, trim

I am building a string with StringBuilder.

```
StringBuilder Q = new StringBuilder();
Q.Append("INSERT INTO ");
Q.Append(_lstview_item);
Q.Append(" VALUES");
Q.Append("("); 
for (i = 0; i < col_no; i++)
{
    Q.Append("'");
    Q.Append(col_value[i]);
    Q.Append("'");
    Q.Append(",");
} 
Q.Append(")");
string query = Q.ToString();
```

However, I am getting a `","` at the end of my string.
I tried using

```
string query = ext.Substring(0, ext.LastIndexOf(",") + 1);
```

to remove the surplus `","`, but this also removes the `")"`.

How can I remove the **last** comma only?

**actual outcome** : `INSERT INTO .... VALUES('1','2','3',)`

**desired outcome** : `INSERT INTO .... VALUES('1','2','3')`

Comment: It's not answering your question, but I really encourage you to use parameterized queries rather than generating them by concatenating strings. There are a tonne of posts on SO about how to do this.

Comment: Why add you `Q.Append(")");` at all if you want to remove the comma first?

Comment: The solution isn't to remove the comma, but to do this differently.

Comment: @TimSchmelter With such reasoning one might ask why it isn't only conditionally added within the loop.

Comment: You are always a [bobby tables](http://xkcd.com/327/) away from ruin!

Comment: Ido not know how to use parameterized queries in my situation. I am extracting the values to be added from a datagridview, That is why I resorted to stringBuilder.

Comment: @GrantThomas: It's more readable and efficient to add one `if` after the loop instead of checking that always in the loop.

Comment: Try my simple Logic way : http://stackoverflow.com/a/18330057/2218635

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This:

```
Q.Append(")");
```

replace with

```
if (col_no > 0)
{
    Q.Length--;
}

Q.Append(")");
```

The check `if (col_no > 0)` is a little overboard, because if there is no column, the query will still fail for other reasons, but if we consider this a template on how to combine strings in a `StringBuilder`, then the check is the *right* thing to do.

Ah... Building a query in that way is the *wrong* thing to do.

Answer (score 18):

You can use the "Remove" method to remove a specific character at a position:

```
query = query.Remove(query.LastIndexOf(","), 1);
```

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest to remove the comma first before you add the last `)`, so:

```
for (i = 0; i < col_no; i++)
{
    Q.Append("'");
    Q.Append(col_value[i]);
    Q.Append("'");
    Q.Append(",");

} 
if(col_no > 0) Q.Length --; // <-- this removes the last character
Q.Append(")");
string query = Q.ToString();
```

However, if you really want to create a sql-query i would strongly suggest to use sql-parameters to **prevent sql-injection**. So don't include the values in your sql-string.

Answer (score 0):

1. the correct way to achieve your goal is to use a parameterized query.
2. there is the possibility to delete the last coma before putting the bracket
3. the pure answer to your question can be this:

.

```
string query = ext.Substring(0, ext.LastIndexOf(",")) + ext.Substring(ext.LastIndexOf(",") + 1);
```

or this:

```
string query = ext.Remove(ext.LastIndexOf(","), 1);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this. simple logic

Check the below if condition in befor append comma line

```
                  **if(i!=(col_no-1))
                    {
                    Q.Append(",");
                    }*
```

With your code .

```
                 for (i = 0; i < col_no; i++)
                  {
                    Q.Append("'");
                    Q.Append(col_value[i]);
                    Q.Append("'");
                    **if(i!=(col_no-1))
                    {
                    Q.Append(",");
                    }**

                  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Replace

```
            Q.Append(",");
```

inside the for-loop with

```
            if (i != col_no - 1)
            {
                Q.Append(",");
            }
```